# Celery: How to Wait nested tasks finish in group

Tags: python, celery, django-celery

I need to make requests to an API with some params and process data from requests one by one. But sometime response data is paginated, means I need to make extra request with same params.
Celery `group` allow us to run tasks one by one, but if tasks produce child tasks, and child tasks can produce more child tasks...,

Is there a way to wait all children tasks finished before run next task in the group? Or maybe celery give us better approach to solve my task?

```
def some_api_call(start_date=None, end_date=None, token_value=None):
    pass


@celery_app.task(name='run_task', max_retries=None, bind=True)
def run_task(self):
    group_items = [
        task1.s('2020-01-02', '2020-01-03'),
        task1.s('2020-01-05', '2020-01-01'),
        task1.s('2020-01-010', '2020-01-04'),
    ]
    group(group_items)()

@celery_app.task(name='task1', max_retries=None, bind=True)
def task1(self, start_date=None, end_date=None, token_value=None, *args, **kwargs):
    res = some_api_call(start_date, end_date, token_value)
    if res['token_value']:
        # NEXT ELEMENT IN THE GROUP SHOULD WAIT UNTIL NESTED CHILD TASKS DONE
        task1.delay(token_value=token_value)
```

Broker - `Redis`.
My possible solutions[pseudocode]:

1. Wait until child tasks done in a parent task

```
    res = task1.delay(token_value=token_value) 

    res.get()
```

Solution is bad - we block tread.
Not sure if celery has await alternative.

2. User `task.retry()` to check if child task is finished.

```
    taskid = task1.delay(token_value=token_value)
    if AsyncResult(taskid).state != "successes": 

      self.retry()
```

So we will retry parent tasks until children tasks finished and don't block the thread.
But like in the first solution: parent tasks processed its data, but state would be retry.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to wait for tasks in a Group to finish, you should use the [Chord](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chords) primitive. Also, if you need your tasks to be executed sequentially (one after the other), then use the Chain primitive. Chord is basically a chain of Group, and a final task...

Comment: can you show me How I can use chord in my situation. If you read my question - I need to wait all child tasks finished before run next task in a group.

Comment: Chord is basically a Group + task that "collects" data after the Group is finished. It is all explained in the documentation pretty well. If you want to run tasks *sequentially*, there is another primitive made for this purpose - Chain.

Comment: Chord doesn't solve my problem, chord is just callback task on group finish. I need to know if task in the group done with all its children tasks

Comment: Then you make a slightly more complex workflow where your "child tasks" are also Chords...